# How to Remove Salt from DB?

Tags: salt

okay I am trying to make a log in form to my website in C# it has md5 + salt.. the problem is salt. md5 I can make work but salt just won't work. I made a php that gets the user name, user group id's etc. I have removed tons of instances of salt in the db and it either destroyed log in, or just did nothing. I am wondering if there is an easy way to remove salt?

Answer (score 2):

What do you think is the purpose of the salt? If you could easily remove it, what would have been the reason to add it? You should really take a few minutes to read a tutorial about [password hashing](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php).

MD5 is not an appropriate choice to hash passwords, because it is ways too fast. One can calculate 8 Giga MD5 values per second with common hardware nowadays, that makes brute-forcing too easy. Instead use a slow key derivation function like BCrypt or PBKDF2.

To answer your question, you need the stored salt to verify the user entered password. If the user enters the password for login, you calculate a hash with the same salt you used to calculate the stored password in the database, then you can compare the hashes.